# Pyspark dataframe replace functions: How to work with special characters in column names?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I need to **replace all blank strings in dataframe with null**.
Ideally, replace function of pyspark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions would do the trick. The code would be `df_test = df_test.replace('', None)`

However, when I have **special characters (dot)** in column names, then it fails with **error** `` AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "NL.Col1" among (NL.Col1, Col2); did you mean to quote the `NL.Col1` column? ``

I have tried:-

- Not passing any list to replace function so that it considers all.
- Passing a list of columns wrapped in `` (as suggested by error)
- Passing list of columns which do not have special character to test out functionality. Still same error occurs.

**Having dot in column name is crucial for downstream task and I should not remove or substitute it.**

Below is a sample pyspark code in case you want to test it.

```
# Create df
df_test = spark.createDataFrame([['a','b'], ['',None], [None, None]], ['NL.Col1', 'Col2']) 
ls_map_col = df_test.columns
print(f"""Original column list: {ls_map_col} """)
ls_wrap_col = [f"`{i}`" for i in ls_map_col]
print(f"""Wrapping in `` looks like this: {ls_wrap_col} """)
# Demonstrate that select works fine with the list when column names are wrapped in ``
df_test = df_test.select(*ls_wrap_col)
df_test.display()

#### ERROR OCCURS HERE when special character like dot is present.
# Try replacing values in column 
df_test = df_test.replace('', None) #, ls_wrap_col
df_test.display()
df_test = df_test.dropna(how='all') # dropna also throws same error as replace
df_test.display()
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 1):

Preserving those periods in your object names is a bad idea. But if you're determined to do it, you can use regexp_replace.  It will kind of suck, because you have to do it for every column you want to replace your empty string in.

```
df_test.withColumn("NL.Col1",regexp_replace("`NL.Col1`",'',None)).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be to rename the column to not include `.` in the name.

```
##Replace . with '_'
df_test.columns = df_test.columns.str.replace('.','_')
```